# Ionic modal value is not getting in onDidDismiss

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing an Ionic app with modal. When I am using `onDidDismiss` method, I am not getting the value from modal to page.

I want to send data when modal `dissmiss()`.

My code is given below.

**home.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-input type="text" maxlength="50" name="name1" placeholder="eg: Software Engineer" (input)="openModalNew();"></ion-input>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, ModalOptions, Modal } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailsPage } from '../details/details'

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController,public params: NavParams) {

}

    openModalNew() {
    let MyNewModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DetailsPage);
    MyNewModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    console.log(data);  // getting as null
    });
    MyNewModal.present();
    }

}
```

**Details.html**

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>ModalPage</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
```

**details.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
})
export class DetailsPage {
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl : ViewController) {

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalPage');
}

public closeModal(){

    let data = { 'name':'kumar','id':'12345' };
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
    }

}
```

Here `onDidDismiss` the value is getting null. How to solve the issue please help me. I tried several times.

Comment: No issue with your code. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1fnrjz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Please re-run the app then try.There is nothing wrong with the code.If still not working you can go for better option like Global provider

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda i have checked your code. but in my code when i adding  let MyNewModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ContactPage); . Showing the error "No compent factory found for ContactPage" . So i use it let MyNewModal = this.modalCtrl.create("ContactPage"); . It is working but not getting value.

Comment: @Joe Try adding ContactPage to entryComponents array of you app.module.ts If you didn't get what I am saying update your question with latest code.

Comment: @ys i got the answer when adding ContactPage to entryComponents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by adding the model "DetailsPage" in entryComponents of **app.module.ts** .

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
DetailsPage
],
entryComponents: [
DetailsPage
],
```

And i change the code in **home.ts** is

```
let MyNewModal = this.modalCtrl.create(DetailsPage);
```

instead of

```
let MyNewModal = this.modalCtrl.create("DetailsPage");
```